# Read email account from Outlook 365 Exchange using Rest Api

Tags: php, office365api, outlook-restapi

I am trying to access a mail account in the same way as you would by using LDAP and then accessing emails.

But this client is using Outlook 365 Exchange.

So do I need to use the Outlook Rest Api?

I found this article:

https://pritomkumar.blogspot.co.za/2016/11/write-php-app-to-get-outlook-office-365.html

Would this do the trick?

I obviously need to "auto connect", by saving the persons email and password in a database.

Your help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook/rest/php-tutorial

This also talks about getting an OAuth token as part of the workflow.